Debezium Server - GCP PubSub - Add a field from outbox table to the header
I'm working with Debezium server and an outbox table to publish a message to PubSub. I've added a filter in the subscription level of pubsub topic to filter out the messages. In order to work this filter, I want to add the filter type as an attribute in the PubSub message. How can I achieve the same with Debezium server? From my understanding, debezium converts its header and put in the attribute of pubsub message. I'm facing difficulty to set my desired value as a header in debezium event from outbox table.
Tried below code and it is not working.
debezium.transforms=outbox
debezium.transforms.outbox.type=io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter
debezium.transforms.outbox.table.fields.additional.placement=event_type:header:eventType

Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Did you try this config?

Do u have an answer? Same problem here.
